# java double number division giving strange output

Tags: java

Found below output strange. Is it really?

```
double rate =  11/12; // outputs 0.0

double rate = 11.00/12; // outputs 0.916666667;
```

Why so much difference?

Comment: first one you have rate as a double but assigned an int division to it. The second case you are dividing a double.

Comment: `double rate = 11/12;`

This does integer division of 11/12 (which is 0) and then stores it in a `double` datatype.

    `double rate = 11.00/12;`
This does floating-point division because there is at least one floating point number in the expression. Therefore all the operands are cast into the highest precision before evaluation.

   `double rate = (double)11/12;`
would give a similar result because in that we are explicitly converting one of them and thereby forcing floating point arithmetic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the 1st case first division is done so an int divided by an int gives a integer i.e, 11/12=0 Then  this integer is converted to double .ie, 0.0. In the 2nd case a double(11.00) is divided by a integer(12).The integer 12 is then automatically type casted to double as division should occur with similar types. This division gives a double value which is exact in reality(0.916666667)

See this link https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html